# How to control checked or unchecked in Stripes Tag checkbox

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, checkbox, stripes

Good day,

I have a String array as follow in my action file:

```
String[] accIds = new String[accountIds.size( )];

accIds[0] = "2105|2";
accIds[1] = "2102|2";
accIds[2] = "2108|2";
accIds[3] = "2101|2";
```

The follow is part of my jsp file:

```
<s:checkbox name="accIds" value="2102|2" disabled="true" /> 
<s:checkbox name="accIds" value="2105|2" disabled="true" /> 
<s:checkbox name="accIds" value="2108|2" disabled="true" /> 
<s:checkbox name="accIds" value="2101|2" disabled="true" />
```

I found that only the second checkbox will be checked (value="2105|2"), which is value equal to the first element of `accIds` array. The other checkboxs are unchecked.

However, If I using Integer Array instead of String Array, and set all the checkbox value to integer, for example 2102, 2105, 2108 and so on, then all the checkbox will checked if the value is inside my Integer Array.

** edit **
Actually my checkbox is generate by a for loop. I write it in that way in question just for easier understanding.

Here is some code of my jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="asAccount" items="${serAccounts}" varStatus="loop">
     <c:set var="accountId" value="${asAccount.accountId}"/>
     <c:set var="serAcctId" value="${serId}|${accountId}" />
     <s:checkbox name="accIds" value="${serviceAcctId}" disabled="true" /> 
</c:forEach>
```

Please advise me what is my mistake on the String Array case.

Comment: How is your jsp built ?

Comment: Hi fxm, done edit my question.